# User Role Association per Domain Entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I have the following structure in my DB:

> ```
> DomainEntities:
>  +EntityID
>  +Name
>  +ParentID
>  +...
>
> Users:
>  +UserID
>  +Username
>  +...
>
> Roles:
>  +RoleID
>  +Name
>
> UserRolesAssociation:
>  +RoleID
>  +UserID
>  +EntityID
> ```

So i want to use MVC's built in authorization attribute to filter action in my controllers that are made by different members.

I what to be able to say if user1 makes a delete action on entity1 or any entity under it i can see if he has the right role to do that and filter the action accordingly.

What would be the best practice to tackle that topic ?
Should i create my own permissions engine that will provide me the answers i need or can i use the existing capabilities ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the best practice to tackle that topic ?

A custom `[Authorize]` seems like a good place to implement this logic.

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            // the use ris not authenticated or not authorized - no need to continue
            return false;
        }

        string username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        // read the entity id that this user is attempting to manipulate
        string entityId = (string)httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] ?? httpContext.Request["id"];

        return IsAllowed(username, entityId);
    }

    private bool IsAllowed(string username, string entityId)
    {
        // You know what to do here - hit the database and check whether
        // the current user is the owner of the entity
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpDelete]
[MyAuthorize]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you .. that actually helps.. i have never created my own custom attribute, that would be a good place to practice :).. one more question you wrote <// read the entity id that this user is attempting to manipulate> but in the current context how can i find out what entity is the user trying to manipulate ?.. should i read it from the query string ..

Comment: Yeap, that's what the line just beneath it does - it's reading the entity id from the RouteData or from the Request. Your controller action must somehow be passed this information.

Comment: I did not thought that i could access the rout data while overriding the attribute... Thanks that worked perfectly ! :)